# load dynamic data in amcharts using java struts 2

Tags: java, json, struts2, amcharts

i want to show var charts using amcharts and data come from database now  varchart is show but problem is its contain only one value out of three please see the below code here i attach my code with json output think here proble is struts.xml

alternative i want to write json file in my project directory see the my java action class (block code) here i write json file and out put is ok but the problem  is how i add file path in  amchart dataloader url: see the example below
https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/dynamically-loading-chart-datasets/

**my js file**

```
   var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {

      "type": "serial",
      //"dataProvider": generateChartData(),
/*        "dataLoader": {
        "url": "getInstituteChartDataListDash.do"
      },  */
      "dataLoader": {
            "url": "getInstituteChartDataListDash.do",
            "format": "json"
          },
      "valueAxes": [{
        "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "gridAlpha": 0.2,
        "dashLength": 0
      }],
      "gridAboveGraphs": true,
      "startDuration": 1,
      "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "totalInstitute"
      }],

      "graphs": [{
            "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
            "lineAlpha": 0.2,
            "type": "column",
            "valueField": "totalMpoInstitute"
          }],


      "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "zoomable": false
      },
      "categoryField": " institute",
      "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "tickPosition": "start",
        "tickLength": 20
      }
    });
```

**my java action class is**

```
public String getInstituteChartDataList(){

        instituteChartList = dashbordsql.getInstituteChartDataList();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        json = gson.toJson(instituteChartList);
         /*try {

             ServletContext context = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
             String path = context.getRealPath("/");

             File file = new File(path+"allPages/homePages/testPage.json");
             System.out.println("Path == "+path);
             System.out.println("json == "+json);
             if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

             System.out.println("file == "+file);

             FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
             writer.write(json);



             writer.flush();
             writer.close();



        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/



        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
```

**and my sql class is**

```
public List<InstituteBasicInfo> getInstituteChartDataList() {
        List<InstituteBasicInfo> instituteBasicList = new ArrayList<InstituteBasicInfo>();
        InstituteBasicInfo instituteBasicBeen = new InstituteBasicInfo();
        boolean fg = true;
        connection = dbConnection.connectDB();

        if (connection == null) {
            fg = false;
        }
        if (fg) {
            try {
                st = connection.createStatement();
                query = "select sum(total_inst) as toIns, sum(mpo_inst) as toMpo, sum(non_mpo_inst) as toNonMpo from ( select count(*) as total_inst , 0 as mpo_inst, 0 non_mpo_inst from institutes where eiin is not null and institute_name_new is not null and stop is null "
                        + "UNION ALL "
                        + "select 0 as total_inst,  count(*) as mpo_inst,  0 as non_mpo_inst    from institutes  where eiin is not null and institute_name_new is not null and stop is null and MPO_STATUS='1'"
                        + "UNION ALL "
                        + " select 0 as total_inst, 0 as  mpo_inst ,count(*) as non_mpo_inst from institutes   where eiin is not null and institute_name_new is not null and stop is null and MPO_STATUS='2')";
                System.out.println("Qry :" + query);

                rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()) {

                    instituteBasicBeen = new InstituteBasicInfo();
                    instituteBasicBeen.setTotalInstitute(rs.getString("toIns"));
                    instituteBasicBeen.setTotalMpoInstitute(rs.getString("toMpo"));
                    instituteBasicBeen.setTotalNonMpoInstitute(rs.getString("toNonMpo"));



                    instituteBasicList.add(instituteBasicBeen);
                }

            } catch (SQLException sq) {
                instituteBasicList = null;
                sq.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                    st.close();
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    instituteBasicList = null;
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return instituteBasicList;
    }
```

**json out :**

```
[{"totalInstitute":"35408","totalMpoInstitute":"25582","totalNonMpoInstitute":"6516"}]
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="*Dash" class="com.dd.dashbord.action.DashbordAction" method="{1}">
    <result type="json">
        <param name="root">instituteChartList</param>
    </result>       

</action>
```

Comment: The issue is likely with your JSON output. Can you post a sample of your output for folks like myself that aren't familiar with struts 2?

Comment: thanks for helping... here i attached my json output

Comment: Your data looks fine. Did you include the dataloader plugin? The `dataLoader` is only available by loading the dataloader plugin file. If you're loading it from the amcharts website, you should have a script tag that looks like this: `<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js"></script>`

Comment: yes i add dataloader plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the problem is my json out put i just change my query now its ok...

```
SELECT 'Institude' INS_TYPE, COUNT (*) AS TOTAL_INST
  FROM INSTITUTES
 WHERE EIIN IS NOT NULL AND INSTITUTE_NAME_NEW IS NOT NULL AND STOP IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MPO' INS_TYPE, COUNT (*) AS TOTAL_INST
  FROM INSTITUTES
 WHERE     EIIN IS NOT NULL
       AND INSTITUTE_NAME_NEW IS NOT NULL
       AND STOP IS NULL
       AND MPO_STATUS = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Non- MPO' INS_TYPE, COUNT (*) AS TOTAL_INST
  FROM INSTITUTES
 WHERE     EIIN IS NOT NULL
       AND INSTITUTE_NAME_NEW IS NOT NULL
       AND STOP IS NULL
       AND MPO_STATUS = '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is how you're defining your graphs. The `graphs` property is an array of `graph` objects. By creating duplicate `graphs` in your config, you're redefining the graphs array to another single element array, rather than including the other graph objects. If you want to show all three properties in your data, your `graphs` array should look something like this:

```
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "totalInstitute"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "totalMpoInstitute"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "totalNonMpoInstitute"
  }],
```

Your updated `categoryField` is referencing a property called `" institute"` (note the space in your string - it's probably wrong) that isn't currently in your data. You'll want to include that in your code that creates your JSON result set.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wuvwLtnq/1/) that demonstrates the correct `graphs` setting using a dummy value for `"institute"` in your sample data.

Comment: hello, thanks for answer, you already see json output here contains three category field level with three value  but problem is categoryAxis show only one category... see your example in fiddle show only "Test" but i want to show three categoryAxis "totalInstitute with value" , "totalMpoInstitute with value" and "totalNonMpoInstitute with value" and when mouse over in category field only show thats category value but your fiddle when mouse over show at a times three value..

Comment: Only one category axis is allowed. Your fields are valueFields since they only contain numeric values. You don't have anything that looks like a category if you compare your data against the [amCharts demos](http://www.amcharts.com/demos). If you want the bars under their own category label then you have to re-arrange your JSON as `[{"category": "totalInstitute", "value": 35408}, "category": "totalMpoInstitute", "value": 25582}, {"category": "totalNonMpoInstitute", "value": 6516}]` and use only one `graph` with a valueField of `value`. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3tg0gqt/1/)

Comment: thaks for replay , yes you are right my json out put is wrong did not match the amchart json formate i just change my query and now its ok..